# I want to bind the legend option with checkbox(show legend or not)

Tags: angular, chart.js

I want legend to be below the chart( position: left bottom), and i want to bind the legend option with checkbox(show legend or not). How can i do that?

**TypeScript:**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html'
})

export class chartComponent {
  public chartOptions:any = {
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [
            {
               ...............

            }
        ]
    },
    responsive: true
  };
  public chartLabels:string[] = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
  public chartType:string = 'bar';
  public chartColors:any[] = [
    {
      // 
    }
  ];
  public chartData:any[] = [
     ............
  ];
```

**HTML:**

```html
    <div style="width:41%; height:41%">
      <div>
        <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
          [legend]="chartLegend"
        [chartType]="chartType"
        [colors] =  chartColors"

        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
        </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to bind legend for checkbox under the chart for above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
        <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
          [legend]="checkboxChecked"
        [chartType]="chartType"
        [colors] =  chartColors"

        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
        </canvas>
      </div>
```

You will have a check box as

```
<input   type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxChecked" /><br>
```

Explanation:

Initialise checkboxChecked:boolean=false; in your component class.

When ever the checkbox is clicked `checkboxChecked`will become `true`, and your legend will be visible.

[legend] property of ng2-charts is a boolean variable as per the docs here as shown below,

[image]

**[Source](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)**

Comment: what explanation you want ?

Comment: how to bind legend to this checkbox by ngmodel

Comment: when checkbox is checked you need to show legend, unchecked - hide legend is your requirement?

Comment: did you use the above solution? if you use you can achieve this. Try the above solution first

Comment: ya i tried it referring to other links too, but im new to this coding and etc.. im not getting exact picture how to use.

Comment: Thankyou, it helps

Comment: @Sai you need two more reputation to upvote this answer